# Validation rule help needed!

Tags: validation-rule

I would really appriceate if anyone can help we with a validation rule
Requirement is depending on the below field status only system admin should be able to unlock the record or change status from submitted to save

```
field1  Sample checkbox is True
field 2 Status  picklist value is submitted
field 3 unlock checkbox only by System Admin
```

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: AND((Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c))  || (ISPICKVAL(Status_vod__c, "Submitted_vod"))&& NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "System Administrator" ))

Comment: this works but even if the filed (Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c = false) it won't allow to update

AND(Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c = TRUE, 
(TEXT(Status_vod__c) = "Submitted")) 
&& $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"

Comment: I just need help to add a condition to this validation rule IF Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c is TRUE then only admin can update

ISCHANGED( Status_vod__c) && NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "System Administrator" ))

Comment: Is this more of a sharing problem? If state A, anyone can edit the record. If state B, only the administrator can edit the record. Can you use workflow or process builder to toggle the owner back and forth between a group and the System Administrator? (System Administrators will always have edit capabilities anyway.)

Comment: yes System admin can always but I need these other users with a different profile to edit the records as well unless the Sample field is True.

Comment: This is not complex but just not getting it appreciate your help 
how to add this field (Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c )condition if true to below existing validation rule

ISCHANGED( Status_vod__c) && NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "System Administrator" ))

Answer (score 2):

It should just be a matter of adding the field with && to your validation rule, since checkboxes are boolean values you can just do the following:

```
Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c && ISCHANGED( Status_vod__c) && NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "System Administrator" ))
```

Comment: thanks for responding Jenny, I tried and it did not worked wondering do I have to use a IF statement or something else?

Comment: @Mirza no need for if statement, maybe try one condition at a time to see where it's getting stuck. Just have that field to start with and add on from there.

Comment: It worked on a different field (text) 
Signature_vod__c <> "" && ISCHANGED(Status_vod__c) && (CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "GILD - NA US Comm Ops - Read Only" ))

Comment: I wonder why it wont work on the check box field (Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c) 
Is_Sampled_Call_vod__c && ISCHANGED( Status_vod__c) && NOT(CONTAINS( $Profile.Name , "System Administrator" ))

Comment: Did u try the checkbox by itself because it for sure works, take a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/advanced_formulas first unit has examples.

Comment: I used a different field (text) and it worked:-) its currently being tested thanks Jenny B.